# Repository commit referenced in another repo as directory

Tags: github

I was looking at the code in a GitHub repository when I found the following:

```
<repo name> @ <commit hash>
```

[image]

I have used GitHub for quite some while now but never saw something like this. What is it and how do I go about doing this in my own repositories?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). They are like shortcuts to specific (commits in) repositories.

To create your own git submodules, from within a local clone, run:

```sh
git submodule add <repository_url>
```